# How to Get/Code Single value of data from dataset/database

Tags: asp.net

this is example of database

---

petType         PetName      PetDetails    PetPrice

----------     ------------    --------------   -------------

cat_***_*___***kitty****_*__*_*___***non****_*__*_*_**_2000.00

dog_**__*chiwa*__*_*___***non****_*__*_*__**_3000.00

bird_***_*_***parrow****_*__*_****non****_*__*_*____**_1000.00

---

the code i made:

**PetStore.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <p>
        <asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle">
           <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
           <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
        </asp:label>
        &nbsp;</p>
</div>
</form>
```

**PetStore.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PetStoreTableAdapter petsAdapter = new PetStoreTableAdapter();
    label1.DataSource = productsAdapter.GetPetData();
    label1.DataBind();
}
```

So those code i made only display all the data on database... What should i do if i just wanted to display single value like "kitty" not the data of kitty, but only the words "kitty" that i want to display on "label1.text" on my page.. thank you

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `Label` has no `HeaderStyle` property. Maybe you're thinking of a `DataGrid`?

Comment: thanks for the reply^^ but still the point is.. that i want to know the script/code that can get the words/value "kitty" from database to my label.text on my page^^ should i do new Query just for petName, i think that must be the way that i'm no need to do new query from database thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ExecuteScalar` to get a single value. Check the link below. It will return the first column of the first row from the result set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Also, check below URL for assigning value from executescalar to label:

http://asp.net-informations.com/data-providers/asp-executescalar.htm

Also, your example is confusing because you have `gridview` in your example and `label1.text` in your description. I'm assuming here you will have a `label`.

Comment: actually.. its not gridview.. its a label.. sorry^^

Comment: You just need to assign the value to label1.Text.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to the exact scenario you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

what the column you have needed specify in the bound field
eg

```
 <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="PetName "  DataTextField="PetName" Visible="false"  />
```

and make AutoGenerateColumns="false"

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle">
         <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="PetName "  DataTextField="PetName" Visible="false"  />
          </Columns> 
           <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />

           <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply^^ but still my point is.. that i want to know the script/code that can get the words/value "kitty" from database to my label.text on my page^^ should i do new Query just for petName, i think that must be the way that i'm no need to do new query from database thank you.

Comment: You can get the specific row access using "where" clause in your select statement else use the following code..!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `Column` values:

```
public DataSet GetPetDetails()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string connectString = constr.GetConString();
    using( var con = new OleDbConnection(connectString))
    using( var cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from PetMaster", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using(var adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            adp.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

To Display `All Column Values` of `'PetName'` with `Comma` Separated:

```
protected void Bind()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = GetPetDetails();
        if (ds != null)
        {
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                {
                    label1.text += dr["PetName"].ToString()+",";

                }
            }
        }
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bind();
}
```

**Single Column & Single Row Value:(Only the word Kitty)**

```
label1.text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PetName"].ToString();
```

**Note: Considering to your above mentioned sample data in table. '0' is the Row Number in DataSet & PetName is the Column.**

Let me know if any issue yet?
Hope this helps you...! :)

Answer (score -1):

For getting only one record from database or one by one record from database,"Data Reader" is Good Approach.Check the site below You can get clear Idea on Data Reader.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/aspnet-difference-between-datareader.html

For example:

```
  SqlConnection connection=New SqlConnection("your connection string");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
      "SELECT  PetName  FROM TableName;",
      connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Label.Text=reader[0].ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
    }
    reader.Close();
```

Comment: -1: this is not the way to use a `using` block. The caller must be responsible for the `SqlConnection`. Similarly, your code needs to put the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` into their own `using` blocks.